# org.opensaml.common.SAMLRuntimeException: Can't obtain SP signing key

Tags: spring, spring-security, saml

Unable to go through realm discovery phase. While the samples code works good with IDP SSO circle. Facing issues when updated our securityContext.xml with our Company's Metadata.xml , imported pfx certificate and added to keystore.

Used below command to add to keystore :

```
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore PFX_P12_FILE_NAME -srcstoretype pkcs12 -srcstorepass PFX_P12_FILE_PASS -srcalias SOURCE_ALIAS -destkeystore samlKeystore.jks -deststoretype jks -deststorepass nalle123 -destalias alias
```

PFB Exception Trace :

```
org.opensaml.common.SAMLRuntimeException: Can't obtain SP signing key
    at org.springframework.security.saml.key.JKSKeyManager.getCredential(JKSKeyManager.java:193)
    at org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataGenerator.getServerKeyInfo(MetadataGenerator.java:205)
    at org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataGenerator.buildSPSSODescriptor(MetadataGenerator.java:329)
    at org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataGenerator.generateMetadata(MetadataGenerator.java:189)
    at org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataGeneratorFilter.processMetadataInitialization(MetadataGeneratorFilter.java:127)
    at org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataGeneratorFilter.doFilter(MetadataGeneratorFilter.java:86)
```

and console messages as below :

> No default metadata configured, generating with default values, please pre-configure metadata for production use
>
> Unable to retrieve keystore entry for entityID (keystore alias): apollo
>
> Check for invalid keystore entityID/alias entry password

Used the `entityBaseURL` as the end party url shared with client. Also tried with entity id that appears in `metadata.xml`.

Any help is truly appreciated.

Comment: improved formatting

Answer (score 1):

While using self-signed Keystore using keytool command, key-pair password (specified for keytool option **-keypass**) and keystore file password must be same.

We can create self-signed Keystore using below command

```
keytool -genkeypair -alias springsaml -keypass <password> -keystore saml-keystore.jks
```

when receive message "Enter keystore password" on terminal, enter the same password, which is provided for keytool option "-keypass"